# CLI : shell can have colors, but PHP cannot output colors, displays ← left arrow instead

Tags: php, shell, colors, command-line-interface

I have a shell that is color capable, but I cannot have a PHP script to output colors.

For instance:

```
$ echo -e "\e[32m Hello"
```

Outputs "Hello" in green as expected, but

```
$ php -r 'print "\e[32m Hello\n";'
```

prints the following in default color:

```
←[32m Hello
```

Any clue of what I should look into ?

[image]

Comment: instead of `\e`, try `\033`, e.g. `php -r 'print "\033[32m Hello\n";'`

Comment: It works for me as you've written it.

Comment: Yeah I already tried with \033, same result, works with `echo -e` but not the PHP bit

Comment: Your terminal might use different escape character. What's the output of `echo -e "\e" | xxd` ?

Comment: This prints: `0000000: 1b0a                                     ..`

Comment: For what it's worth, since I'm suspecting this is the root of the problem, I'm running `echo $0` = `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe"`

Comment: Hm... and what's the output of `php -r 'print "\e"' | xxd` then?

Comment: `0000000: 1b                                       .` (ie 1b instead of 1b0a and one dot instead of two)

Comment: So it's basically the same (0a is a line feed and is irrelevant), as I suspected. This seems to be interoperability/BC break issue, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears colored console output is not supposed to work reliably on windows as of yet (see [PHP bug #72768](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72768) and the follow-up [PR #2103](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2103)). It worked on some combinations of windows/git shell/php, though.

So here's your options as far as I understand:

- you may try to downgrade to working versions
- try your luck with [ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon)
- use another terminal such as powershell or [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/)
- or wait for PHP 7.2 release where this issue is ought to be fixed

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks a lot.